# How to upload a zip file from shared path to object storage using soa?

Tags: xml, oracle-soa

I have the requirement of placing a file (zip file) from shared path to oracle object storage using oracle SOA. When I do this with the text file for poc. I am able to place a file in object storage but the file is wriiten in xml format the file didn't get the file content also.

I am using the xml input for rest connecting to object storage binary format to place the file in object storage. But I need to configure it to the exact format of it. Any one guide me to do this.

This is Rest XML Payload I am using. Do I need to use any other payload

```
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FileName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="File" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
```